# On the largest and smallest topology on a given set.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{ \mathscr{T}_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in \Sigma }$ be a family of topologies on a given set $X$.

Question: How can I find the unique smallest topology on $X$ containing all the collections $\mathscr{T}_{\alpha} $? The unique largest topology contained in all the topologies $\mathscr{T}_{\alpha}$.

#### Attempt:

I know $\mathscr{L} = \bigcap \mathscr{T}_{\alpha}$ is a topology and is contained in all the topologies $\mathscr{T}_{\alpha} $. How can I show that it is indeed the largest with this property? Also, I don't know what to choose for the smallest topology.

thanks for any help.

Comment: For the other question is think you should consider the topology generated by the union of all the others. (But I do not really know you terminology so I might be off.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Concerning your attempt**:

Suppose that $\tau$ is a topology that is contained in $\mathcal{T_{\alpha}}$
for each $\alpha\in\Sigma$. So if $U\in\tau$ then $U\in\mathcal{T_{\alpha}}$ for
each $\alpha\in\Sigma$ or equivalently $U\in\mathcal{L}:=\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Sigma}\mathcal{T_{\alpha}}$.
This proves that $\tau\subseteq\mathcal{L}$ so confirms that $\mathcal{L}$
is the 'largest' with the mentioned property.

**Concerning the smallest topology containing all topologies** $\mathcal T_{\alpha}$.

Defining $\mathcal{W}=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Sigma}\mathcal{T_{\alpha}}$.
you are looking for the smallest topology $\mathcal{O}$ that
contains $\mathcal{W}$. Then $\mathcal{O}$ must contain the collection:
$$\mathcal{W}':=\left\{ W\mid W\text{ is a finite intersection of elements in }\mathcal{W}\right\} $$
The collection $\mathcal W'$ can be shown to be a basis for a topology. Based on this we conclude that $\mathcal{O}$ must
contain the collection: $$\mathcal{W}'':=\left\{ W\mid W\text{ is a union of elements in }\mathcal{W}'\right\} $$

and that $\mathcal{W}''$ **is a topology**. So we
come to $\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{W}''$.

In fact this way any collection $\mathcal{V}\subseteq\wp\left(X\right)$ gives rise to
a topology $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{V}}$ that is constructed as described
above (and identifying the 'empty intersection' with $X$). This $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{V}}$ is the topology generated
by $\mathcal{V}$.

Comment: Thanks you. However, I don't understand the first line on the part concerning the smallest topology. Why are we looking at the smallest topology containing the union?

Comment: If it contains all topologies then it will contain also the union of all topologies. Do you agree on that? The converse of this is also true. So 'containing all topologies' and 'containing the union of all topologies' are equivalent conditions.

Comment: How do I prove $\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{W}''? $  It is trivial that $\mathcal{O}\subset \mathcal{W}''[\because \mathcal{O}$  is the smallest topology containing  $\mathcal{W}$]. How do I prove the converse? My attempt------- Suppose  $X\in \mathcal{W}'' \implies X$  is the union of  $\mathcal{W'}$. Each $\mathcal{W'}$ is the intersection of $\mathcal{W}$. also we have $\mathcal{W}\subset \mathcal{O}.$ We have $\mathcal{O}$ is a topology. So, $X \in \mathcal{O}$. Hence,  $\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{W}'' $

Comment: Am I correct drhab?

Comment: @N.Maneesh I think your idea is correct, but I would rather say: $\mathcal W\subseteq\mathcal O\implies\mathcal W'\subseteq\mathcal O\implies\mathcal W''\subseteq\mathcal O$. The first implication because topology $\mathcal O$ is closed under finite intersections and the second implication because topology $\mathcal O$ is closed under unions. Btw, the other side is indeed not too difficult but I would not call it trivial. For that it must be shown that $\mathcal W''$ *is* a topology.

Comment: here in my proof I assumed that assertion W'' is a topology on X

Comment: what happen if we interchange the definition of $\mathcal{W'}$ and $\mathcal{W''}$?

Comment: would we get the same topology on X?

Comment: please help me drhab

Comment: @N.Maneesh The answer is most probably that we do not get a topology in general if the definitions are interchanged. I must think about an eventual counterexample. Why are you so anxious to know this?

Comment: drhab. since, I am a learner ;]

Comment: can you help me with the counter example

Comment: it seems correct for me.

Comment: @N.Maneesh I will let you know if I found one, but do not make promises concerning the time I need for that.

Comment: sorry drhab it was wrong.