# Show that a subset of a Dynkin's class is also a Dynkin's class

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $\mathbb{K}$ is a Dynkin's class, let 
$$
\mathbb{K}_A=\left\{B\in\mathbb{K}\mid A\cap B\in\mathbb{K}\right\}
$$

My textbook claims that it is easy to show that $\mathbb{K}_A$ is also a Dynkin's class. But I can't see why.

Also, if $\mathbb{D}\subset \mathbb{K}$ and $\mathbb{D}$ is stable under intersections, then if $A,B\in\mathbb{D}$, then $A\cap B\in \mathbb{D}\subset\mathbb{K}$ can be reformulated as: if $A\in\mathbb{D}$, then $\mathbb{D}\subset\mathbb{K}_A$. Why is that?

Comment: What is your definition of a Dynkin’s class?

Comment: The book uses the same as the first one in this Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be the underlying set. We need to show that $\Omega\in\Bbb K_A$, that $C\setminus B\in\Bbb K_A$ whenever $B,C\in\Bbb K_A$ with $B\subseteq C$, and that $\Bbb K_A$ is closed under unions of countable non-decreasing chains, where

$$\Bbb K_A=\{B\in\Bbb K:B\cap A\in\Bbb K\}\;.$$

Clearly $\Omega\in\Bbb K_A$ iff $A\in\Bbb K$, so I will assume that this is the case. Now assume that $B,C\in\Bbb K_A$ with $B\subseteq C$. Then $B\cap A,C\cap A\in\Bbb K$, and $B\cap A\subseteq C\cap A$, so $$(C\setminus B)\cap A=(C\cap A)\setminus(B\cap A)\in\Bbb K\;,$$ and therefore $C\setminus B\in\Bbb K_A$. The proof that $\Bbb K_A$ is closed under unions of countable non-decreasing chains is similar; you should try to complete it on your own.

For the other question, let $\Bbb D\subseteq\Bbb K$. Assume first that $A\cap B\in\Bbb D$ whenever $A,B\in\Bbb D$, i.e., that $\Bbb D$ is closed under intersection. Let $A\in\Bbb D$ be arbitrary. Then for each $B\in\Bbb D$ we have $B\cap A\in\Bbb D$ and hence $B\cap A\in\Bbb K$. But $$\Bbb K_A=\{B\in\Bbb K:B\cap A\in\Bbb K\}\;,$$ so for each $B\in\Bbb D$ we have $B\in\Bbb K_A$, and it follows immediately that $\Bbb D\subseteq\Bbb K_A$.

However, it’s possible to have $\Bbb D\subseteq\Bbb K_A$ for each $A\in\Bbb D$ even if $\Bbb D$ is not closed under intersection. For example, let $\Bbb K=\wp(\Bbb N)$, and let $\Bbb D$ be the family of $2$-element subsets of $\Bbb N$. $\Bbb K_A=\Bbb K$ for all $A\in\Bbb K$, so we certainly have $\Bbb D\subseteq\Bbb K_A$ for all $A\in\Bbb D$, but the intersection of two distinct members of $\Bbb D$ is *never* a member of $\Bbb D$.

Comment: (+1) But I will upvote later because you already got the max of votes for today. Thanks Prof. Brian. If you don't mind bothering you again, I have a question on a bounty. Can you help me so I can give you the points because the bounty expires today and I don't have a satisfactory solution: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016543/on-the-largest-and-smallest-topology-on-a-given-set

Comment: A question. You state that $\Omega\in\Bbb K_A$ iif $A\in\Bbb K$, and the assume that this is the case. But is that really enough? I think you can show that $A\in \Bbb K_A$ by noting that $A\cap \Omega\Rightarrow A\subset \Bbb D\subset \Bbb K$. But does showing that $A\in\Bbb K_A$ proof that $\Omega\in\Bbb K_A$?

Comment: @RudFaden: $\Omega\in\Bbb K_A$ is precisely equivalent to $\Omega\cap A\in\Bbb K$, from the definition of $\Bbb K_A$. And once you have this, it follows immediately that $A\in\Bbb K_A$, simply because $A\cap A=A\in\Bbb K$.